# Upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 not working

Tags: upgrade

I automatically get a question if I want to upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04. I answer "yes" and short after the process has start I get:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirror.neology.co.za/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

When I close the display the system reverses what has been done to that point and later asks if I want to upgrade again. 
Every time I get the same results.
Is there some I should be doing to get the process to successfully upgrade ?

Comment: Open your "System Settings" → "Software & Updates" and in the "Ubuntu Software" tab, select a different server in the "Download from" list. Then try to update again.

Comment: I tried "Server for the United Kingdom" and got the following results:

Comment: I tried "Server for the United Kingdom" and got the following results: W:Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

, W:Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

, W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

, W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/stable/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

Comment: I ignored the upgrade message for a few days and then tried again, still using the Server for the United Kingdom. The upgrade went through without any further problems. I don't know what changed but I'm glad the upgrade worked. This question can be closed. thanks.